# ¿Cómo soportar números en notación científica (1.2E-3) al usar console.readline() en c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

el día de hoy cuando estaba leyendo un correo de un usuario que descargó mi aplicación de consola escrita en C#, la cual tiene un sistema de conversión de unidades, me comentó que cuando introducía 2.35*E+4, el programa arrojaba un error. Lo cual es obvio al no estar configurado que se pueda identificar este valor.

Y aquí es donde llega mi pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?
Yo he estado buscando en google pero no he obtenido ningún resultado.

El código que tengo ahora mismo es este:

```
public static void TmpCel()
    {
        bool rep = true; //Declaramos un booleano en condicion true para poder ejecutar un while a continuación
        while (rep)
        {
            Console.Write($"Introduzca una temperatura en {temps[0]} a convertir:\n>> ");
            try
            {
                double cels = double.Parse(Regex.Replace(Console.ReadLine(), "[.,']", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));//Hacemos que el usuario introduzca una cantidad por la consola, y obligamos a convertirla a double.
                //En caso de no poder por el motivo que sea, pasaremos al bloque catch.
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0} {1} a {2} es: {3}", frmcv, temps[0], temps[1], frms[4]);//Para ahorrar espacio utilizamos variables para acortar el código
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a {2} es: {3}", frmcv, temps[0], temps[2], frms[2]);
                Op_Temp.OpCelFahrKel(cels);
            }
            catch (Exception e) when (e.GetType() != typeof(FormatException))//Aquí creamos un encapsulador que en caso de error va a comprobar que el tipo de excepción producida no sea FormatException.
            //Y en caso de que sea FormatException, el programa ejecutara el código del catch que contenga el argumento FormatException 
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;//Cambiamos el color para que quede mejor.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;//Ponemos el color inicial
            }
            catch (FormatException e)//Este es el bloque catch que se ejecutará en caso de que la excepción producida sea FormatException
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(FrmExc);//Llamamos a la constante declarada al principio del programa
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n");//e.Message nos permite mostrar una descripción corta del error, sin mostrar código del programa.
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
           }}
```

La comprobación se que ha de ir justo donde declaro el double "cels" y obtengo el valor del Console.ReadLine.

Comment: Leyendo la respuesta que has aceptado, el título de la pregunta es incorrecto. Cuando escribes  `123E5`, esa `E` significa _**por diez elevado a**_, pero ese no es el [número de euler](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_e), identificado como `e` (minúscula), en una expresión tal como `e^x`. He editado el título de tu pregunta por la misma razón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabajar con exponentes funciona bien si usas el tipo de dato correcto

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string cadena = "2.35E+4";
        double numero = Convert.ToDouble(cadena);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result= {0}", numero);
    }
}
```

- usa el tipo `double`
- ademas no uses el `*` eso no es correcto

Tambien puede controlar el error sin un `Exception` usando el `double.TryParse()`

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string cadena = "2.35E+4";
        double numero = 0;
        
        if(!double.TryParse(cadena, out numero))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El numero no es valido");
            return;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result= {0}", numero);
    }
}
```

En tu codigo en particular no entiendo porque escribes todo en una sola linea, haciendo el codigo complicado de entender

```
string cadena = Console.ReadLine();
double cels = double.Parse(cadena);
```

no tienes que reemplazar nada de puntos o comas, si es un tema de configuracion regional debes trabajar con la cultura que apliques, pero sino solo valida si en input es un numero.

Si quitas la puntuacion cambias el valor para un numero con exponente

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, tienes razón con el pequeño detalle del `*`, es lo que fallaba. En cuanto al código la única diferencia es que el valor a convertir lo introduce el usuario y no el programador. De todas formas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.